# Check values in an array in a while loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have a function that returns an array

```
$statusall = Getstatusall();
```

The array looks like this
this

```
$statusall = ['inprogress', 'complete', 'Failed', 'inprogress', 'staring'];
```

I want to loop the Getstatusall function until all the array values are 'complete' or 'failed'
How should I do that in PHP?

Comment: Is that really how the array looks?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all or even researched PHP looping controls?

Comment: `while(array_diff(Getstatusall(), ['complete']) && array_diff(Getstatusall(), ['failed'])) {}`

Comment: When you say `I want to loop the Getstatusall function until all the array values are 'complete' or 'failed'` Do you mean you want to repeatedly call the `Getstatusall()` function until it only returned an array containing the values `complete` or `failed`? Please remember we are not clairvoyant and we are not looking over your shoulder

Comment: ___Also Note___ the `$statusall ={inprogress , complete ,Failed , inprogress,staring }` this does not indicate an array in PHP. So can you show us a `print_r($statusall)` so we can be sure what is really in that varibale

Comment: @RiggsFolly Array ([0] => Complete[1] => In progress[2] => In progress ).

Comment: It is always BETTER to edit your question and place the extra details into theere

Comment: Do you mean you want to repeatedly call the Getstatusall() function until it only returned an array containing the values complete or failed? . Yes that's correct

Comment: THen the answer below from @RobinGillitzer seems like it would do that

Comment: If you want to get an idea what im trying to do. I'm still learniing php. I'm uploading video contents using a php script . I send HTTP PUT request though a loop for all the files. What i want is that i want to get the final status of the files whether ingested or failed using HTTP GET.

Comment: @user3205478 Scroll a little bit down and try the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example echo `There are values not complete or failed. Repeat.` while the function `Getstatusall()` returns an array with values that are not `complete` or `failed`.

```
while( array_diff( Getstatusall(), ['complete', 'failed'] ) ) {
  echo "There are values not complete or failed. Repeat.";
  // you can even do something else or nothing
}
```

If you want to get the `final result`, this may helps:

```
while( array_diff( $status = Getstatusall(), ['complete', 'failed'] ) ) {
  echo "There are values not complete or failed. Repeat."
  // you can even do something else or nothing
}
var_dump( $status );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. i'll try that